# Geb - ChromeOptions not being used

Tags: selenium-chromedriver, geb, chrome-options

[Geb test ignoring GebConfig.groovy file launched in IntelliJ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52743048/geb-test-ignoring-gebconfig-groovy-file-launched-in-intellij) helped me get the ChromeDriver to be used, but now I have the problem that ChromeOptions are not being used despite being supplied.

I took the solution provided and just added the assignments found in other StackOverflow solutions:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions

System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "my/path")


// This was one option suggested, but I'm trying the assignment inside the environment block.
// I tried this way, too.
//    driver = {new ChromeDriver()}


environments {
    chrome {
       driver = {
           ChromeOptions opts = new ChromeOptions()
           opts.addArguments("--user-data-dir=/home/guy/.config/automation-google-chrome/")
           opts.addArguments("--start-maximized")
           new ChromeDriver(opts)
      }
    }
}
```

Now the browser comes up fine, but the `opts` are not used: not maximized, and the browser look-and-feel is obviously not right.  I had the same problem when I was using straight Selenium, and I solved it by using the user-data-dir above.   Using same ChromeDriver, too.

The program output says:

```
Starting ChromeDriver 2.20.353124 (very long number here) on port 25082
```

Tried (deprecated) `DesiredCapabilities`, but same.

TIA

Comment: Are you sure that you are running in `chrome` geb environment so that the `driver` closure that sets up `ChromeOption` is actually executed? You could verify that by throwing an exception from within that closure and seeing your test failing to start up.

Answer (score 0):

It's a small thing, but [the docs show](http://chromedriver.chromium.org/capabilities#TOC-Start-Chrome-maximized) providing args to ChromeOptions without the "--" prefix.

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("start-maximized");
```

Comment: didn't have an effect for me

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "my/path")
```

I don't believe that this operation is supposed to take place in the GebConfig.groovy file. And that maybe what is causing your problems. I am not 100% sure though. Everything else looks fine to me (except the "--" before each command), and I have used chrome options successfully before, and the only difference I see between my setup and yours is that this line

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "my/path")
```

for me is inside of my build.gradle file, and not inside of the GebConfig.groovy file. Try moving it into your build script and see what happens

Comment: I need to take a few Gradle tutorials, I think.
I set the property in the `build.gradle` file, but not using the same line verbatim.
I did


    test
        { 
             systemProperties "webdriver.chrome.driver": "/home/myname/chromedriver"
}                          So your suggestion to move the property assignment to the build file did indeed work, but now I need to figure out how to set the options there as well.

Comment: @Guy I don't think you should have to set the options in the build.gradle. I know for my projects I still set all my options in the `GebConfig.groovy` while I set my system variables in my `build.gradle`. Sorry I am not an expert on this, I just have  used chrome options before and this is how I got it to work. the only difference between my script and yours was the system property thing. other than that you shouldn't have to chnage anything.